# I want to get local time in shell script in the specified format HH:MM:SS

Tags: shell

I want to get startTime as start of current time (for eg current time is 12:55 pm) then `startTime` will be `12:00:00` and endTime will be `12:59:59.`
I tried using `startTime="$(date +'%H:%M:%S')"` but this is giving time according to UTC time format i.e: `07:25:43`. But I want result according to my local time zone. Zone is '+0530'.

Comment: What is the setting of 'TZ' env var ?

Comment: @dash-o I am geeting the result in UTC time format. I want in IST format where zone will be '+0530'

Comment: Did you try setting your timezone? For example, setting your timezone to `Asia/Kolkata` using `export TZ=Asia/Kolkata`

Comment: I guess you were trying to get 12hr time instead of 24hr time syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the TZ before you run `date` like:

```
export TZ=Asia/Kolkata
startTime="$(date +'%H:%M:%S')"
```

or in one line:

```
startTime="$(TZ=Asia/Kolkata date +'%H:%M:%S')"
```